# Shortcodes breaking Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am creating new shortcodes for Wordpress on my local version of a Wordpress website.

In functions.php, I am adding for example:

```
function shortTest() {  
    return 'Test for shortcodes ';  
} 

add_shortcode('shortTestHTML', 'shortTest');
```

Adding the function only is OK, but when I add the add_shortcode() portion, I get a major issue.

It breaks something somehow and I get 500 errors, meaning I can't even load my website locally anymore.

Any thoughts???

Thanks so much!

EDIT:

From PHP Error Log:
[21-Jun-2011 19:02:37] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function add_shortcode() in /Users/jonas/Sites/jll/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4505

Comment: And what is the error message that PHP throws on you? Check your PHP error log.

Comment: [21-Jun-2011 19:02:37] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function add_shortcode() in /Users/jonas/Sites/jll/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4505

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Make sure that you have included `shortcodes.php` file somewhere (for example, in `wp-load.php` or whatever other more appropriate place may be).

```
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/shortcodes.php' );
```

2) Make sure that this file does exist on your installation (which I think you have otherwise we would see a different error).

3) Where do you call this function from (I see it is called from `functions.php`, but which place)? Possible problem here -- `functions.php` is loaded prior to `shortcodes.php`, and if you do use that `add_shortcode` function before `shortcodes.php` is loaded you most likely will see this error. Double check your code in that place -- maybe move the call to `add_shortcode` to another place.

Comment: 1) could the theme i'm using prevent the loading of shortcodes.php and replace it with another include?

Comment: 2) it exists... and 3) I calling it at the last line of functions.php

Comment: _"3) I calling it at the last line of functions.php"_ That is the problem. You really should call it later -- when `shortcodes.php` is loaded (for example, at the end of `wp-settings.php` file -- but I'm not 100% sure how correct this approach is).

Comment: OK thanks, but according to Wordpress' documentation, you should add this in the functions.php... mmmm weird... thanks for your help!

Comment: @jonasll I'm not saying "Do not add to functions.php" -- What I'm trying to say is change the way you invoke/call `add_shortcode()` function. Maybe it needs to be added into some already existing function in functions.php that will be called when all modules are loaded. I have no WordPress sources near ATM, so cannot confirm my thought.

Answer (score 4):

mentioned `functions.php` is not in `wp-include/ directory`.
it is in: `wp-content/themes/<your-theme-name>/functions.php`

Comment: how does this help resolving the issue ?

Comment: You should create shortcode in wp-content/themes/<your-theme-name>/functions.php
wp-include/functions.php is not correct file for adding a shortcode.

Comment: This was the right answer for me. THANKS! I was modifying the wrong functions.php file.

Comment: This was the right answer for me as well, I did put my code in the wrong _functions.php_ file!

Comment: This answer could be written more clearly, but yes the was the problem for me too - wrong functions.php!  So thanks!

Answer (score 2):

adding this in functions.php you say?  Well I don't know about that, the way I did it was create a folder inside the wp-content/plugins folder, e.g. shortcodetest.

Inside this folder create a `shortcodetest.php` file.

in that file you basically write your code:

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: ShortCodeTest
  Plugin URI: http://www.example.net
  Description: Print a test message
  Version: 0.1
  Author: anonymous
  Author URI: http://www.example.net
 */

add_shortcode('shortcodetest', 'shortcodetest_function');

function shortcodetest_function() {
    return "test of shortcode";
}
```

?>

Then you login as admin, you will see a plugin ShortCodeTest, activate it.  Then you can use the shortcode in your posts.

Note that the comments are important... they show up in the plugin description.

Answer (score 1):

I got a way to execute them but it's a little triky :)

You need to change a little bit your template by putting your shortcode (for example: [inline ....]) between `<shortcode></shortcode>` then

Here is the function to place at the end of your function.php.

```
function parse_execute_and_echo_shortcode($_path) {
    $str = file_get_contents($_path);
    while (strrpos($str, "<shortcode>")) {
        $beginShortcode = strrpos($str, "<shortcode>");
        $endShortcode = strrpos($str, "</shortcode>");
        $shortcode = substr($str, $beginShortcode + 11, $endShortcode - ($beginShortcode+11));
        $shortcode = do_shortcode($shortcode);
        $str = substr_replace($str, $shortcode, $beginShortcode, $endShortcode + 12);
    }
    echo $str;
}
```

Then you can call `function parse_execute_and_echo_shortcode` and giving it the path to your file containing the shortcodes.

Hope that can help someone

Answer (score 0):

Check your error.log file (it should be in your apache log folder).

It probably has to do with add_shortcode not existing as a function.

Comment: [21-Jun-2011 19:02:37] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function add_shortcode() in /Users/jonas/Sites/jll/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4505

Answer (score 0):

Put your shortcode in the file `/wp-includes/shortcodes.php` this way you make sure it will be loaded when all the blows and whistles are up and running.